# How can I see when an answer was migrated?

Tags: feature-request, migration

I've been checking out some questions, and I saw some of them were migrated questions. And I'm wondering if it's possible to see when a question was migrated.

If there is no functionality like that, I would love to see it. Since it gives the users of the target site a reference point with the possible current answers.

Perhaps just something simple, like when you mouse over "migrated" to see a detailed date.

Comment: I don't get it! There is a banner saying "migrated" in migrated questions. But I think that's not your point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're really curious, you can follow the link back to the original site, where you can hover over the time it was migrated/locked. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399025).

Comment: I'm a blind fool.